# GC in python: what will this behave?

Tags: python

A python class A:

```
a = A()
array.append(a)
```

...
some operation triggers a's method b()

```
in a.b():

array.remove(self);
# will this make the self be freed? as the only reference has been removed from array.
# access the a's data...
```

Comment: I assume this is after `del a` as well?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do.  The garbage collector isn't normally observable behavior in the first place.

Comment: Why do you care when something gets garbage collected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the method is executing, you still have a reference(`self`) to `a` .

Only once the method completes is `a` eligible for collection.